# zend framework 2 viewModel it's not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have the example Album running in ZF2, for lear, I try to use a new module in ZF2, that call Emails, its all working, the folder configurations, modules, routes, controllers, etc..

My problem is that the ZF2, cant recognize where my views are. the folder is there, and the index.phtml is also there. but I still have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "emails/emails/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php:451
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\View\View.php(203): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\View\View.php(230): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\View\View.php(196): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(128): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> #4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Ob in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php on line 451

I think this is because it can't find the folder and archive `emails\emails\index`.
Some idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you include a template_map entry in your module configuration? In the config file you should have something like this to resolve templates.

```
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map'             => array(
            'emails/emails/index' => __DIR__ . '/../views/emails/emails/index.phtml',
            'web/index/index'     => __DIR__ . '/../views/web/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'           => __DIR__ . '/../views/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'         => __DIR__ . '/../views/error/index.phtml',
            'layout/layout'       => __DIR__ . '/../views/layouts/welcome-page.phtml',
            'forms/registration'  => __DIR__ . '/../views/forms/registration.phtml',
            'test'                => __DIR__ . '/../views/test.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../views',
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Could you explain why you have to use layout/layout instead of just layout?

Comment: You can name it whatever you wish. I just put in layout/layout quickly but you can name it 'layout/default' or just 'default' or you can use 'layout/otherlayout' or 'layout/favoritelayout'. ZF2 lets you use this shorter and easier to remember name instead of having to type out the full path. It's like an alias to your layout. ZF2 does the same with controllers when you add them to the controller list.